# Check if each element in an array is a positive, whole number, not a float

Tags: php

To start, I'm still a noob with php, and much of what I've learned is from problems being solved across this site that I have also had myself.

I've found the answers here for all of my original questions, but when I put them all together I can't get get the code to work.

I have a basic form that is posting to itself using PHP_SELF. I want all input from the $_POST array to be checked to make sure that it is (1) a positive integer, (2) a whole number, and (3) does not include a decimal.

```
if( !empty($_POST ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $amount ) {
        if( !is_int($amount) || $amount < 0 || is_float(amount) ) {
            die( 'All data must be positive integers.' );
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I type into any of the input fields it always returns the "die" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$amount` is a string so [`is_int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) will always fail, try [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead

```
if( !empty($_POST ) ) {
    $options = array(
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => 0
        )
    );
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $amount ) {
        if( filter_var($amount, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) === false ) {
            die( 'All data must be positive integers.' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the same thing on the PHP manual page about is_int and strings. I tried your code and it still only returned my die() error. I even created a whole new page with just a simple form to isolate the problem and it again would always fail. And lastly, I took out the "options" flag and it still continued to fail.

Comment: @dustbowl are you sure all your input are integers, do a var_dump($_POST) to see.

Comment: After I did a var_dump I saw that my SUBMIT button was always posting "submit" in the post array, so that's why it continued to fail. The code seems to work perfectly now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I want to also say that many of my attempts to test the code were done using "0". Through some searching I've found that FILTER_VALIDATE_INT has trouble with "0" while in an 'if' statement and will always return false. http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/664/filter_validate_int-0

Answer (score 3):

`is_float(amount)`

Should be

`is_float($amount)`

Comment: Even after fixing my typo, all input still fails the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your code. Replace `is_float(amount)` with `is_float($amount)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $amount) {
        if(!(is_int($amount) && $amount >= 0)) {
            die( 'All data must be positive integers.' );
        }
    }
}
```